How do I get W3Schools to print '&not' from a string and not replace it with '¬'
I'm trying to run a simple for loop to build some URLs for work. I run it in a W3Schools Python installation.
But the URL has &notify in the string and the &not part is replaced with the character ¬. How do I escape it so it will just print &not?
Here's my code:
man_ids = ['1215', '1216', '1217']
a = 'https://DOMAINURL/cgi/editor.cgi?article='
z = '&context=STRUCTURELABEL&notify_authors=0&window=abstract&withdraw_for_author=Withdraw+submission'

for x in man_ids:
    print(a + x + z)

This is what it's returning:
https://DOMAINURL/cgi/editor.cgi?article=1215&context=STRUCTURELABEL¬ify_authors=0&window=abstract&withdraw_for_author=Withdraw+submission

I've tried to use raw string literals and it still isn't working. It just puts the '¬' symbol in quotes.

Looks like w3schools' online tools are about as good as their content...

This is a bug in the W3Schools output rendering. You can replace &not with &amp;not to get the output you're looking for. (Or use a real Python installation where this doesn't happen in the first place.)
